# Any other gotchas with chained insertion operators?

Tags: c++

So, I was messing around with C++ earlier today, in particular chained insertion operators. And I noticed something that seemed very odd to me.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

size_t& foo(size_t& n) {
    ++n;
    return n;
}

int main() {
    size_t bar = 5;
    cout << bar << " a " << foo(bar) << " b " << bar;
    cin >> bar;    //Ignore this, it's only here as an easy way to keep the window open
}
```

Running this, rather than giving `5 a 6 b 6` actually gives `6 a 6 b 5`. Apparently, the insertion operands are evaluated right-to-left, but then printed left-to-right, which would explain why the updated value appears before the function call, and the original value after.

Of course, this could be fixed by simply having `cout foo(bar)` on its own line, but I digress.

Are there any other weird things like this that I should be aware of when chaining insertion operators? Also, does anyone know *why* the insertion operator does this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are reading bar twice and referencing it once for a function call, which increments it. That function call is indeterminately-sequenced with respect to the reads, which are unsequenced to each other, so any ordering is allowed, and it is unspecified which you get.

You don't quite have Undefined Behavior (everything goes), but Unspecified Behavior is not much more fun. These are the four valid outputs:

```
5 a 6 b 5
```

```
5 a 6 b 6
```

```
6 a 6 b 5
```

```
6 a 6 b 6
```

Comment: Ah, thank you. I'd never heard of that - I had no idea it was actually an issue. The language I'm most familiar in is Python, where I can't recall this ever being an issue.

Comment: Is it? I am curious as to which compiler/platform did he use, because the `cout << a << b(a) << a` should be read as `((cout.insert(a)).insert(b(a))).insert(a)` and the parentheses are sequence points, aren't they? (and I ran his program and got 5 6 6...)

Comment: Actually, the only sequence points in his example are: After evaluation of all function argumants but before execution of the function. Draw yourself a graphic and you'll see that both reads and the write can occur at the same time. So, not enough sequence points, specifically none between the two reads and one write of bar.

Comment: FWIW the concept of a 'sequence point' has been removed from the latest standard, and operations are defined as being either sequenced or unsequenced in relation with each other (in this case they are of course unsequenced).

Comment: @user657267: Thanks for the update. Not sure I like it, but at least it's only a linguistic change... Hm, that change might actually make sense.

Comment: -1 Sorry, that is incorrect. There's no undefined behaviour here, only unspecified. Evaluations of argument expressions are sequenced before the execution of functions's body. Evaluations in the calling function are indeterminately sequenced to the execution of the called function (which means that functions calls *do not* interleave).

Comment: @jrok: Corrected long ago. Now completely rewritten.

Answer (score 3):

The "chained insertion operators" are just function calls. C++ has a few simple rules about the function calls in that statement:

1. Function calls in a single statement do not interleave - one is finished before the next one starts. (I.e. no multi-threading inside a statement)
2. When the return value of one function call is the argument to another, the first function call must happen before the second.

There's no rule that multiple arguments to a single function must be evaluated consecutively or immediately before the call - the set of ordering rules is really short.

Now what we see in the chain is that the different `operator<<` calls are indeed chained: the second call uses the return value of the first. That's why these operators all return `std::ostream&`. Thus, your output appears in the correct order.

`foo(bar)` by the same logic must be called *before* its return value is printed. But it can be called at any prior time. Recall there's no rule that 2 arguments to a single function must be evaluated at the same time. The two arguments to the third `operator<<` call are the return value of `foo(bar)` and the return value of the second `operator<<`. So, both must have happened when the third value is printed. It follows that the number printed after `a` is 6.

If you state that the result should be `5 a 6 b 6`, you are assuming that the second argument to the fifth call is evaluated after the second argument to the third call. There simply is no rule about that.